# Makefile not working with cygwin

Tags: makefile, cygwin

I just installed cygwin with C++ compiler and Perl on my windows machine. Whenever 
trying to compile the C++ files with the makefile I get the following error:

```
>make
Cant find C:\Program on PATH
```

Not sure what path is exactly missing and where I can change it...

Answer (score 3):

You should install cygwin in C:\, not in C:\Program Files\ - the latter often causes problems because of the space, as is the case here.

Comment: I have it installed in C:\cygwin

Comment: then the source tree of what you are compiling is in C:¥Program files¥ ?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a space in your PATH environment variable.  Wherever you set the path, you might use an 8.3 filename instead of an extended filename, or you might encapsulate the section with spaces in quotes.  For example: PATH=c:\windows;"c:\program files\foo"

Comment: Maybe because perl is installed in C:\Program Files?
Which path do I have to alter, the one in the environemnt varible of the PC or one in Cygwin?